# Python Click: Error: Missing argument while calling the --help flag

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

This is my code:

```
@click.group()
@click.pass_context
@click.argument('CHALLENGE', type=int)
def challenge(ctx, challenge):
    ctx.obj = Challenge(challenge=challenge)

@click.group(invoke_without_command=True, cls=PhaseGroup)
@click.pass_obj
@click.argument('PHASE', type=int)
def phase(ctx, phase):
    # Something

challenge.add_command(phase)
```

Together these commands are supposed to work like.

```
cli challenge 1 phase 1
```

Which works as intended by executing properly.

But when I use --help or define any other flags on phase, it throws

```
cli challenge 1 phase 1 --help

It throws Error: Missing argument "PHASE".
```

I searched SOF and found [python click app is failing with indication of "missing argument" but cannot locate the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272584/python-click-app-is-failing-with-indication-of-missing-argument-but-cannot-loc) This is a user who had the same issue, but I didn't quite understand the answer.

I cannot make the arguments optional since it is a crucial part of making the CLI work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental problem your code is facing is that you are trying to use a group like a command.  There are at least two ways to improve the situation:

#### Use a command:

The terminal enties are usually a `click.Command` not a `click.Group`.  If you change `phase` to a `click.Command` the help will work as expected.

```
@challenge.command()
@click.argument('PHASE', type=int)
def phase(ctx, phase):
    ....
```

#### Use `no_args_is_help` with the group:

If you pass `no_args_is_help=True` to the `click.Group` constructor, the help will be displayed as you hoped.  But unless you have a really good reason for this I would instead suggest using a `click.Command` as shown above.

```
@challenge.group(invoke_without_command=True, no_args_is_help=True)
@click.argument('PHASE', type=int)
def phase(ctx, phase):
    ....
```

#### Side Note, you don't usually need `add_command()`:

You do not generally need to use:

```
@click.command()
def my_command():
    ....
challenge.add_command(my_command)
```

You can instead do:

```
@challenge.command()
def my_command():
    ....
```

#### Test Code:

```
import click

@click.group()
@click.pass_context
@click.argument('CHALLENGE', type=int)
def challenge(ctx, challenge):
    ctx.obj = challenge

@challenge.command()
@click.pass_obj
@click.argument('PHASE', type=int)
def phase1(ctx, phase):
    """Phase1 Command"""
    click.echo((phase))

@challenge.group(invoke_without_command=True, no_args_is_help=True)
@click.pass_obj
@click.argument('PHASE', type=int)
def phase2(ctx, phase):
    """Phase2 Group"""
    click.echo((phase))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        '--help',
        '1 phase1',
        '1 phase1 --help',
        '1 phase1 2 ',
        '1 phase1 2 --help',
        '1 phase2',
        '1 phase2 --help',
        '1 phase2 2 ',
        '1 phase2 2 --help',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            challenge(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Test Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] CHALLENGE COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  phase1  Phase1 Command
  phase2  Phase2 Group
-----------
> 1 phase1
Usage: test.py phase1 [OPTIONS] PHASE

Error: Missing argument "PHASE".
-----------
> 1 phase1 --help
Usage: test.py phase1 [OPTIONS] PHASE

  Phase1 Command

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
-----------
> 1 phase1 2 
2
-----------
> 1 phase1 2 --help
Usage: test.py phase1 [OPTIONS] PHASE

  Phase1 Command

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
-----------
> 1 phase2
Usage: test.py phase2 [OPTIONS] PHASE COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Phase2 Group

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
-----------
> 1 phase2 --help
Usage: test.py phase2 [OPTIONS] PHASE COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Phase2 Group

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
-----------
> 1 phase2 2 
2
-----------
> 1 phase2 2 --help
Usage: test.py phase2 [OPTIONS] PHASE COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Phase2 Group

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] CHALLENGE COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  phase1  Phase1 Command
  phase2  Phase2 Group
```

Comment: The primary reason I didn't use @challenge.command() in phase is that phase needs to be a group. I have more subcommands of the format `cli challenge 1 phase 1 subcommands` So I needed phase as a group. Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Also, I couldn't use the decorators @challenge.command() along with @click.group(), that's why I had to resort to adding it separetely.

Comment: You can use `@challenge.group()`.  So does `no_args_is_help` not do what you need?